# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__user__xxx'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.user'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>)

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2, sqlsrv

I'm usnig SQL Server for my Yii2 project and successfully connected and run migration.

I want to register the new user from my yii2 project to my database, but I got this error from SQL Server.=:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__user__xxx'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.user'. The duplicate key value is (NULL).

Here is the executed query:

```
INSERT INTO [user]
            ([username],
             [auth_key],
             [password_hash],
             [email],
             [user_type],
             [status],
             [created_at],
             [updated_at])
VALUES      
('andhy', 
 'EIrQRO31WLuDGDPoSIkz_wTWEzjGzIK0',
 '$2y$13$1cWynvtIyDA.7I3nyvKqmuq6KT5XPsNc6LaJ04MrWmiNpqP2.vraS',
 'my.account@gmail.com',
 'backend',
 10,
 1496125394,
 1496125394)
```

The unique key is only [id] (as PK), [username], [email], [password_reset_token].

I think the [id] field must be selected in query and set IDENTITY_INSERT to be ON but that is not a good solution for me.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, there's a constraint on your table that is preventing you enter a duplicate key.

Comment: i just using the default migration from yii2 for create the user table

Comment: @DavidG I know the meaning of the error. i've make sure there is no duplicate entry for [username], [email], [password_reset_token] field. only [id] field cannot perform auto incrementing like MySQL when [id] field is not set.

Comment: You either have to explicitly provide the value of `ID` field, or enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` so that auto-increments workds as expected when no value is provided. I can't think of any other alternative.

Comment: @MartinSmith `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [username] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [auth_key] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 [password_hash] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [password_reset_token] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [email] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [user_type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [status] [smallint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((10)),
 [created_at] [int] NULL,
 [updated_at] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED `

Comment: What is the constraint `UQ__user__xxx`? That will tell you which columns are part of the key that is giving you the error. Also, please [edit] your question rather than adding code in comments.

Comment: Your create table above is truncated, but I created a table assuming the rest was the following and your insert query worked fine ([ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 0):

password_reset_token is being inserted as null.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have auto incremented ticked column for id in user table.
since it takes same value which was earlier id stored for next operation

Answer (score 0):

If you still encounter this cause it works on MySQL and not MSSQL, then add the following lines on your user model:

```
[['username'], 'unique'],
[['email'], 'unique'],
```

In other words, change from:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }
```

to:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username'], 'unique'],
            [['email'], 'unique'],
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }
```